# Google maps API : custom infowindow : V2 : Input element not clickable : G_MAP_FLOAT_PANE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to make a custom infowindow. Version = 2.
I have added my DIV to the map as follows -

> $("#infoWindowClass").appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_MARKER_MOUSE_TARGET_PANE));

The infoWindowClass is -

`#infoWindowClass

{

    position:absolute;

    padding:10px;

    height: 155px;

    width: 225px;

    background-color: #E7F8CD;

    color: #3F3F3F;

    border:0.5px solid #8D8D8D;

    font-size:80%;

}`

Per documentation, this is above all other DIV layers.

This DIV has two input fields, however I can't click on any of them.
I manually added the z-index to 990 for this DIV but the input fields are still not clickable.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, instead of assigning my layer to a specific google-map layer, I left it out.
I mean, I commented it this -

> $("#infoWindowClass").appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_MARKER_MOUSE_TARGET_PANE));

And viola ! It worked 8-)
For anyone in the same boat.